# How can I click the first item in searchview suggestion list in Espresso?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have a search view, when I type "Example" as the key word, it will show me a drop down suggestion list which contains 2 items with text "Example". I mean for some reason the suggestion list has 2 item with the same name.

When I do following code:

```
onView(withText("Example"))
.inRoot(withDecorView(not(is(mActivityRuleSaves.getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView()))))
.perform(click());
```

it will give me the exception, the ambiguous view since there are 2 item in the list has the name "Example".

So my question is how can I choose and click the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you figured out already? If not, then I use `onData` instead of `onView`:

```
onData(anything()).atPosition(0).check(matches(hasDescendant(withText(("Blah")))));
onData(anything()).atPosition(1).check(matches(hasDescendant(withText("Blah")))).perform(click());
```

Hope this helps.